# *** /lib/modules/6.2.9-200.fc37.x86_64/build: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compilation, fedora

I'm using `Fedora 6.2.9-200.fc37.x86_64`

I'm trying to compile a driver, but when I run make command breaks with `/lib/modules/6.2.9-200.fc37.x86_64/build` error.
[Driver](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu)

I found that `/lib/modules/6.2.9-200.fc37.x86_64/build` it's a link pointing `/usr/src/kernels/6.2.9-200.fc37.x86_64`, and in `/usr/src/kernels` there aren't any dir. So I tried to create it and re-run. But it give me another error.
I also have seen another articles about the error but they couldn't make it clear to me.
Do you see any error or it's from Makefile?

Sorry about my English...

Comment: You'll need to install the kernel headers for your module to build against. There will be a package for it, most likely called "kernel-headers".

Comment: I've missed write that I've verified the linux headers were installed. Thanksss.

Comment: Maybe you should post the actual error messages, rather than just telling us there was an error. Also, that driver doesn't seem to have been updated since kernel 5.8.7. There's a good chance it just won't work on 6.2.9. The Linux kernel developers make breaking changes all the time.

Comment: The error was literally the title, but your comment gave me the solution, I found another driver that was able to compile without errors. Because was currently updated. Thanks so much.